# Kotlin MainActivity Imports not registering

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are trying to add the thumbnail of a youtube video and link it to the youtube app through code. We have synced all implementations to the build.grade. (app) file but the imports just don't work and show up in red. Is it possible we are using old imports that just don't work anymore?

We have tried looking up the imports and it did not result in anything. We tried retyping imports instead of copy pasting it into the IDE which worked before but it does not work now. Theres more errors within the code but I believe it is because of the imports not going through so some of these tools will not work.

Implementations added to build.grade (app)

`implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.31.3'`

`implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev20220225-1.31.3'`

`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'`

Code for main-activity

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    private lateinit var youtube: YouTube

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        // Initialize YouTube API client
        youtube = YouTube.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            null
        ).setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name)).build()

        // Load the thumbnail of the video with the given ID
        loadThumbnail("VIDEO_ID_HERE")
    }

    private fun loadThumbnail(videoId: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val thumbnailUrl = getThumbnailUrl(videoId)

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                // Load thumbnail into ImageView using Glide library
                Glide.with(this@MainActivity)
                    .load(thumbnailUrl)
                    .into(imageView)

                // Set click listener on ImageView to open the YouTube app
                imageView.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:$videoId"))
                    intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getThumbnailUrl(videoId: String): String {
        // Search for the video with the given ID
        val searchResponse = youtube.search().list("id").apply {
            q = videoId
            type = "video"
            fields = "items(id(videoId))"
            maxResults = 1
        }.execute()

        // Get the first search result, which should be the video we're looking for
        val searchResult: SearchResult = (searchResponse.items as List<SearchResult>)[0]

        // Get the URL of the default thumbnail for the video
        return "https://img.youtube.com/vi/${searchResult.id.videoId}/default.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the build pane at the bottom of the IDE for errors importing your dependencies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.